# RandomUnderSampler' object has no attribute 'fit_resample'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, imblearn

I am using `RandomUnderSampler` from `imblearn`, but I get the following error. Any ideas? Thanks

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
print('Initial dataset shape %s' % Counter(y.values.squeeze()))
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_undersampled, y_undersampled = rus.fit_resample(X, y)
y_undersampled = y_undersampled.squeeze()
```

output:

```
Initial dataset shape Counter({0: 2499739, 1: 1558})

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4fe9dcfbd68e> in <module>
      1 print('Initial dataset shape %s' % Counter(y.values.squeeze()))
      2 rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
----> 3 X_undersampled, y_undersampled = rus.fit_resample(X, y)
      4 y_undersampled = y_undersampled.squeeze()
      5 

AttributeError: 'RandomUnderSampler' object has no attribute 'fit_resample'
```

main libraries I am using:

```
imbalanced-learn==0.3.3
pandas==0.24.2
numpy==1.15.4
scikit-learn==0.19.2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method `fit_resample` was introduced lately to `imbalanced-learn` API. Either update `imbalanced-learn` or use `fit_sample` instead.

Comment: Had a similar problem few days back. Had to use `fit_sample` from version `0.6.2`

Comment: @Pramit Same issue here using the version `0.7.0` and `0.22.1` sci-kit version.

Comment: I solved this problem by updating the `scikit-learn` version to `0.23.1`